# RxJS - Catch and carry on

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

I'm struggling to handle errors with Rx in the manner I expected.

When I have an Observable (for example, from a click stream) and an exception occurs I want to catch it but carry on. All the solutions I have tried catch the error then end the Observable. Is there a way to catch and carry on?

As an example the Observable below will emit "1", then "Error", but never  "3".

```
var range = Rx.Observable.range(1,3)
    .map(function(i){
      if(i === 2){
        throw "Error";
      } else {
        return i;
      }
    })
    .catch(function(e){
      return Rx.Observable.return(e)
    });

range.subscribe(function(i){
  console.log(i)
});
```

Comment: The only way to carry on with the source sequence is not to throw. Could you tell us what your real use case is?

Comment: The observable contract is that it must emit to an observer the pattern: (OnNext)* (OnCompleted | OnError).  So the moment a sequence emits OnError it ends.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold the real case is a click event observable, which `flatMap()` to a http request observable. If/when the http request fails, the click observable is no longer emitting.

Answer (score 9):

While your expected behavior cannot be achieved because of the Observable contract `(OnNext)* (OnCompleted|OnError)`, there are practical ways of properly working around this by introducing a hot Observable.

```
let hotRange = Rx.Observable.range(1,3).publish();

let safeRange = hotRange
  .map(function (i) {
    if (i === 2) {
      throw "Error";
    } else {
      return i;
    }
  })
  .retry();

safeRange.subscribe(i => console.log(i));
hotRange.connect();
```

[See the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jitoyajuje/1/edit?js,console). The `range` Observable you mentioned in the question is a cold Observable. It [behaves as a movie](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md), so if an error happens and we resubscribe, we need to subscribe from the beginning of the "movie", that is, `1` then `"Error"`.

You probably had an implicit assumption that `Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)` was a live Observable, i.e., "hot". Since it isn't, I made `hotRange` above using `publish()`. This way, it will emit its events independently of its subscribers. If we want to be able to "carry on" after an error, we need our source ("hotRange") to be without errors. That's why `range.map( )` isn't the hot Observable. `retry()` will catch errors on `hotRange.map( )` and replace it with `hotRange.map( )`. Because `hotRange` is hot, every execution of `retry()` will be different, since it doesn't remember previous values emitted by `hotRange`. So when the error caused by `2` is replaced by `hotRange.map( )` in the retry, `hotRange` will subsequently emit `3`, and pass the map function without errors.

Comment: This makes sense if there will only ever be a single exception. To work in the n-case `retry` would probably be better instead of `catch`.

Comment: @AndréStaltz. But in the subscribe method, an error handler not emitted nothing. How can we get an error in the error handler?

Comment: @xgrommx That could be provided by the `retryWhen` operator.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Could you provide a simple example for this?

Comment: @AndréStaltz I'm in the same boat as @xgrommx. A solution I have is to `.catch()` into a `Subject` which is purely for errors.

Comment: You cannot subscribe for errors and still expect to subscribe for subsequent onNext events. That is simply against the Observable contract. You can however forward errors into a Subject as you said, where the `onNext` values of the Subject are errors themselves. But you are getting close to an anti-pattern, so perhaps would be better to know your real use case.

Comment: @AndréStaltz I am in a simliar dilemma. I have to catch the error and give a notification that an error has occurred, but after giving that notification I need my original observable to keep on listening for more notifications. i.e a catch and retry. My use case is that of a redux action. If search is successful, return success action, otherwise give error action but continue with original observable after that. Is injecting values in a Subject the only way to go about it?

Comment: @channikhabra might be relevant: the new RxJS has the `caught` Observable (the source to be continued) as the second arg to the catch function. You can use it to continue the original observable. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/src/operators/catch.ts#L23

Comment: @AndréStaltz Thanks. Looks like `caught` is useable for my use-case. In current stable Rx (4.0.7) however, this can easily be achieved with a nested Observable which can decide which action to emit next. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893425/rxjs-catch-and-retry-an-observable/33899267#33899267

Comment: retryWhen is working for me to both keep the observable alive and notify the error: `.retryWhen(errors => errors.do(err => console.error(err)))`